# Iperf tool installation error on linux

Tags: iperf

error while insallation the iperf tool in linux
could not find the correct pacakage    libiperf.so.0(64bit)

```
error failed dependencies
libiperf.so.0(64bit) is needed by the iperf -3.1.2-1.1.x86_64

When trying to install iperf on the linux server
```

tried with lib files from 
https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libiperf.so.0()(64bit)
but not sucessful

request you share the correct pacakage

Answer (score 0):

In the above error clearly mentioned that the libiperf.so.0 is missing.

if you are trying to install the rpm using

```
rpm -ivh iperf3-3.1.2-1.1.x86_64.rpm
```

then 1st install the library using 
**for Opensuse**

```
zypper install libiperf0
```

**for ubuntu**

```
apt-get install libiperf0
```

after sucessfull installation try installing the rpm again.